# How can I remove duplicate JS bundle created by webpack4?

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

I am trying to create JavaScript Library and CSS bundle (extracting all CSS used in a single file) using webpack 4.

My webpack.config.js file configuration is as below:

```
var path = require("path");
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin"); // Require  to generate html file
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin"); // Require  to generate css file

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + "/src/app/index.js", // webpack entry point. Module to start building dependency graph
  output: {    
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"), // Folder to store generated bundle
    filename: "chart.min.js", // Name of generated bundle after build
    library: ["Chart"],
    libraryTarget: "umd"
  },
  module: {  // where we defined file patterns and their loaders
      rules: [ 
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: "babel-loader",
            exclude: [
              /node_modules/
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
              "css-loader"
            ],
            exclude: [
              /node_modules/
            ]
          } 
      ]
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: "chart",
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: "all",
          enforce: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [  // Array of plugins to apply to build chunk
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: __dirname + "/src/public/index.html",
          inject: "body"
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css"        
      })    
  ],
  devServer: {  // configuration for webpack-dev-server
      contentBase: "./src/public",  //source of static assets
      port: 7700 // port to run dev-server
  } 
};
```

By running above code, I am getting following files in my dist folder
"1.chart.min.js", "chart.min.js", "chart.css", "index.html"

May I know why I am getting "1.chart.min.js" file and How can I stop generating same?

Comment: In your app, are you lazily loading any module?? Is there any `import().then` statement in your code?

Comment: No, specifically I have below import statement:
'import util from "./util";
import style from "../public/css/Gauge.css";'

Answer (score 1):

You may like to clean the output path using [**clean-webpack-plugin**](https://github.com/johnagan/clean-webpack-plugin)

Comment: Thanks, I have added this, but my problem is my configuration everytime generates "1.chart.min.js" file, So how can I stop it?

Comment: So you have two files with same name in same folder?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in que. "1.chart.min.js", "chart.min.js" are two files having identical content.

Comment: is this the complete webpack config file?

Comment: Yes.( Sorry I could not add less than 15 characters in the comment, so added this line)

Comment: Try:

```plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin({
        protectWebpackAssets: false,
        cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['1.chart.min.js']
    })
  ]```